# How to do conditional rendering according to screen width in react?

Tags: reactjs, responsive, conditional-rendering

there is a problem, I don't know how to implement the component technically correctly.
I want to do conditional rendering of an element
depending on the device screen.
Example: if the screen is less than 700 px then I make one conclusion, if more then the second

```
if(window.innerWidth > 700) {
   return(
    <Content>
       1 
    </Content>)
};
return (
<Content>
       2
</Content>)
```

I use react, next js, and typeScript technologies

how to do this?

Answer (score 15):

Create a width state in your component, and update state on window resize event, like this:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = React.useState(window.innerWidth);
  const breakpoint = 700;
  React.useEffect(() => {
   const handleResizeWindow = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    // subscribe to window resize event "onComponentDidMount"
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResizeWindow);
    return () => {
      // unsubscribe "onComponentDestroy"
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResizeWindow);
    };
  }, []);
  if (width > breakpoint) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Component 1</h3>
        <p>Current width is {width} px</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Component 2</h3>
      <p>Current width is {width} px</p>
    </div>
  );
}


class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <App/>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use `ternary` operator in react like this for conditional rendering of component.

```
{ window.innerWidth > 700 ? (
   <Content>
       1 
   </Content>
 ) : (
  <Content>
       2
  </Content>
  )
}
```

Comment: Just tried with a similar solution. It works on initial rendering but it won't work if the `window.innerWidth` is changed afterward.